# Outlook Add-in with Dependency Injection (IoC)

Tags: dependency-injection, ioc-container, autofac, outlook-addin

I'm writing an Outlook add-in with a separate core class library. I'm trying to use an Ioc container (Autofac), but I'm a bit lost as to how I register the Outlook session as a dependency of my services.

I'm a DI newbie.

In my ThisAddIn.cs file I instantiate a bootstrapper in my class library:

```
public override void BeginInit()
{
  _core = new AddInBootstrapper();

  base.BeginInit();
}
```

The AddInBootStrapper.cs class is in my Core class library. Its constructor looks like so:

```
public AddInBootstrapper()
    {
        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

        containerBuilder.RegisterType<OutlookService>().As<IOutlookService>();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<EmailPrintService>().As<IPrintService<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem>>();

        _container = containerBuilder.Build();
    }
```

My OutlookService class has a dependency on the Outlook session (ThisAddIn.Application.Session):

```
public OutlookService(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace session)
    {
        _session = session;
    }
```

I'm not sure how to wire this up in a correct manner. Do I simply pass the Session into the Bootstrapper class through its constructor then wire it up, or is there another/better way?

```
_core = new AddInBootstrapper(this.Application.Session);
```

Comment: I've found something that works, but not sure if ideal. See below

Answer (score 1):

I have ended up passing the session from the ThisAddIn class to the Core class library, it works OK.

```
public AddInBootstrapper(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace session)
    {
        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

        containerBuilder.Register(c => new OutlookService(session)).As<IOutlookService>();
        containerBuilder.RegisterType<EmailPrintService>().As<IPrintService<Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem>>();

        _container = containerBuilder.Build();
    }
```